# Importing multiple XML files that have varying fields - check isset() or some Java equiv?

Tags: java, android

I'm importing multiple XML files that have the same tag names, but some of the files are without a few of the tags.

My imports work great for all files that have every "field" (ie `<title></title>`), but I get `java.lang.NullPointerException` when I try to set a value of my class to an item that doesn't exist in the XML file.

For example:

```
for(NewsItem item : parser.getParsedItems())
{
    Article a1 = new Article();
    a1.title = item.title.trim();
    a1.subtitle = item.subhead.trim();
    //...
}
```

This works great for most, but if one of them doesn't have a "subhead" tag, then I get the error.

Is there some way I can check IF it's been set or has value prior to trying to set it to the "title" value of my Article? (as an example).

I tried `if(!item.title.isEmpty())` but that still gives the error.

(or is there a better way that I'm overlooking?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if the element doesn't exist, it can't be checked for isEmpty() because it is null.

```
if(item.title != null && !item.title.isEmpty()) {
    // Yay, we have something useful!
    a1.title = item.title.trim();
} else {
    // Perhaps we should give a default value?
    a1.title = "";
}
```

Comment: Or `a1.title = item.title == null? "" : item.title.trim();`

Comment: Indeed, that's a more concise way of setting the value on a1 and is equally good. I personally avoid the ternary operator because I find it a little less clear/readable. It's really a matter of preference I suppose. You're right though that the isEmpty() is not necessary once we know it is not null.

Comment: I thought I tried that and got an error about not being able to compare a string to boolean or something - seems to work though, so apparently I did it wrong last time! :)  Thanks!

Comment: And thanks, Joop too - thought I usually don't like the shorthand, this is a one liner, so I might in this case.

Comment: Note - I cannot use isEmpty - says it's not available for a String ...maybe I'm on an older version or something.

Comment: Yeah, that requires at least Android 2.3.x. isEmpty() only checks if length() == 0 so you could swap that in instead.